# Watson natural language understanding

Tags: ibm-watson

I have customized a  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MghXz.png)model, but when I did the connection like in screenshot, I just get nothing in body request, its only return language. I really want to get the relationship beetwen the entities

Comment: Which entities do you think in your odd looking text input should be detected?

Answer (score 0):

NLU by default will not find any entity/relation in the string used as test. If your use case are going to deal with strings like that and you need to understand how the information is related, I would suggest working also with WKS, creating a model specific for your domain (juridic as it seems), then using the NLU with your new model from WKS to get the entities and relations.

Another suggestion, if you only want to test if your code is right, you can use the [NLU demo](https://natural-language-understanding-demo.ng.bluemix.net/), to see if something would be extracted from the input

Also, never post your API Key.